# Two vague steps in the proof of Harnack inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the book [*Elliptic and Parabolic Equations*](http://ifile.it/ukwajg) and the proof is excerpted from page 133-136.

1. In Theorem 5.1.3:
   [image]

   it claims that
   $$C((1-\theta)R)^{-n/2}\left(\sup_{B_R}u\right)^{1-p/2}\left(\int_{B_R}u^p\,dx\right)^{1/2}\le\frac{1}{2}\sup_{B_R}u+C((1-\theta)R)^{-n/p}\|u\|_{L^p(B_R)}$$
   , according to [*Young's inequality with ε*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Elementary_case). 
   But I cannot figure out what are the a, b and ε.
2. Later in Lemma 5.1.3:
   [image]

   here I don't understand how it magnifies the factor $(|\nabla\eta|+\eta)^2$ (it seems to suggest that $|\nabla\eta|+\eta\le 2^{(i-1)}$). Though I know $|\nabla\eta|\le2^iC$ and $0\le\eta\le1$, I need a further explanation.

Any hints are appreciated :)